# Set selected row in UIPickerView from Parse objects

Tags: ios

In a view there is a text field and a picker view. The picker view items are loaded from a Parse query.
The text field text is always one of the picker view items.
The picker view selected item must be the same as the text field text. That is my code for the moment, but it throws an exception:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"floors"];
[query whereKey:@"floor_restaurant" equalTo:self.restaurante.objectId];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
```

if (!error) {
        _pickerData = objects;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [objects count]; i++)
    {
        if ([[objects objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString: self.floor_name_text.text]){
            [self.floor_picker selectRow:i inComponent:0 animated:YES];

            break;
        }

    }

    [self.floor_picker reloadAllComponents];



}
else {
    NSLog(@"error");
}
```

}];

That is the exception:

```
2015-02-28 21:03:20.707 RestAppXXI[675:60b] -[PFObject isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I am new to Parse with iOS and any help is welcome.

EDITED :

```
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    PFObject *object = _pickerData[row];

        return object[@"floor_name"];


}
```

Comment: Show your code for the `titleForRow:forComponent:` method.

Comment: The error seems to be inside your `for` loop where you compare `[objects objectAtIndex:i]` to some string. The array contains `PFObject` instances, not strings.

Comment: @rmaddy, and do you know how could I compare one of the PFObjects rows with the text field text?

Comment: You need to compare the text field text to a specific value in the `PFObject`.

Comment: @rmaddy, you propose to change this: [objects objectAtIndex:i] for a specific value in the PFObject ?

Comment: @rmaddy, I have change the line as follows:  if ([[[objects  objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"room_floor" ] isEqualToString: self.floor_name_text.text]){ now the exception is not thrown, but the picker view selects always the first item, not the item that is equal to the text field text

Comment: @rmaddy, I have solved my issue, please take a look at my answer to see it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of rmaddy and a little searching, I have resolved my issue, here is the final code that works:

```
[PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"floors"];
    [query whereKey:@"floor_restaurant" equalTo:self.restaurante.objectId];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            _pickerData = objects;


            for (int i = 0; i < [objects count]; i++)
            {
                NSString *textoactual = self.floor_name_text.text;


                if ([[[objects  objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"floor_name" ] isEqualToString: textoactual]){

                    [self.floor_picker reloadAllComponents];
                    [self.floor_picker selectRow:i inComponent:0 animated:YES];

                    break;
                }

            }





        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }
    }];
```